# Interpretation of the complement $S_5 \setminus D_6'$.

Tags: group-theory, geometric-interpretation

On account of a homework question

$$ \text{does there exist an injective homomorphism } D_6 \to S_5 \text{ ?}$$

which I solved positively, I raised the question

$$ \text{what does the complement } C = S_5 \setminus \langle (45),(12)(345) \rangle \text{ look like?} $$

If one interprets the subgroup $H = \langle (45),(12)(345) \rangle$ of $S_5$ as $D_6$, the symmetries of the hexagon, then what interpretation can we give to $C$?

Comment: $\langle(12),(12)(345)\rangle$ is abelian, so there is no way that could be isomorphic to a dihedral group. In fact it is the same as $\langle(12),(345)\rangle$, and is only of order $6$.

Comment: I edited: $\langle (12),(12)(345) \rangle$ should have been $\langle (45), (12)(345) \rangle$. Note that $(45)$ is in the normaliser of $\langle(12)(345)\rangle$ but not in $\langle (12)(345) \rangle$ itself.

Comment: Complements of subgroups are not generally meaningful. (But quotients of normal subgroups are.) In this case, if you could identify six things that $S_5$ acts on in a way such that your $H$ permutes them like $D_6$, then $C$ would be the permutations that _don't_ permute them like something from $D_6$.

Comment: Indeed, that is what $C$ would be. I'm wondering what kind of permutations these elements of $C$ are. Can we say that they permute the six points like elements from some other group $G$ for instance?

Comment: @MusséRedi No, because the complement of $H$ is not a group.

Comment: @MusséRedi Complements of algebraic substructures within an algebraic structure are generally not algebraic structures. I'm reasonably sure that within $C$, there are two permutations that multiply to a permutation that _is_ in $C$. So $C$ won't be closed under multiplication. For that reason and others, $C$ won't be a group. Here's another reason: $C$ does not contain the identity. But anyway, can you imagine a meaning for $C$ involving things "that are not $D_6$", and yet two such things multiply to be within $D_6$?

Comment: @alex.jordan $C$ would informally be the "irreversible" non-rigid symmetries of the hexagon. And by irreversible I mean that there is no element in $C$ by which the hexagon can be "reconstructed" to its original state, for what it is worth to be a physical interpretation. By the way, why do you suggest that two things should multiply to be within $D_6$, since we are talking about $C$ and not $D_6$?

Comment: I'm pointing out that your $C$ is not an algebraic structure, since you cannot generally combine two things from $C$ and always expect to get back a thing that is in $C$.